# Plotting Acclerometer Data With Respect To Time

Tags: python, plot

So I am trying to plot accelerometer data with regards to time, my csv reads like this(columns -> time, x, y, z):

```
1518999378635,2.275090217590332,8.601768493652344,3.691260576248169
1518999378653,2.38462495803833,8.633491516113281,4.0964789390563965
1518999378658,2.449866771697998,8.506000518798828,4.082113742828369
1518999378667,2.4372973442077637,8.166622161865234,4.016273498535156
1518999378675,1.8381483554840088,8.848969459533691,4.086902141571045
1518999378681,1.1402385234832764,8.762179374694824,4.225766181945801
1518999378688,1.7818846702575684,8.652046203613281,3.6110546588897705
1518999378694,2.076371431350708,8.80467700958252,4.0527849197387695
1518999378700,2.3720552921295166,8.471882820129395,4.120420932769775
```

My initial bet (as given below!) was to use a scatter with time as color, however the output is, well, not very obvious.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Plotting Accelerometer Data")
    acm_data = genfromtxt("acm_data.csv", delimiter=',', names="time, acc_x, acc_y, acc_z")
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    x = acm_data["acc_x"]
    y = acm_data["acc_y"]
    z = acm_data["acc_z"]
    c = acm_data["time"]

    ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=c, cmap=plt.hot())
    plt.show()
```

The output looks viz:

[image]

and is not very interpretable. What would be the best way to handle this?
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps break the plot into 3 2D subplots of x, y, & z acceleration?

Comment: @DavidOwens Any links etc.? I am not really a data science guy, so that I get it correct and not to some wrong result because I misunderstood you. Also how do I factor time?Thanks.

Comment: Heres a matplotlib example for subplots: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-subplot-py Time is the same for all of your datasets so just use it for the x-axis on all the subplots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3]

x_accel = [5, 6, 3, 4]
y_accel = [2, 7, 6, 8]
z_accel = [1, 2, 3, 4]

plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.plot(x, x_accel, '.-')
plt.title('A tale of 3 subplots')
plt.ylabel('X acceleration')

plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.plot(x, y_accel, '.-')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Y acceleration')

plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.plot(x, z_accel, '.-')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Z acceleration')

plt.show()
```

Generates:
[image]

Of course you'll have to mess with your axes and what not to make the presentation of your data as clear as possible. But in general, this is much clearer than what is posted in your question.

Comment: When my data size is large, i.e. 1000 then which graph should be used for better visualization and how?

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's my answer (break it into 3 2-dimensional plots):

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Plotting Accelerometer Data")
    acm_data = genfromtxt("acm_data.csv", delimiter=',', names="time, acc_x, acc_y, acc_z")
    fig = plt.figure()

    x = acm_data["acc_x"]
    y = acm_data["acc_y"]
    z = acm_data["acc_z"]
    t = acm_data["time"]

    for dat, num, axis in zip((x,y,z), range(311, 314), "XYZ"):
        plt.subplot(num)
        plt.plot(t, dat, ".")
        plt.title("%s-axis" %axis)
    plt.show()
```

Which gave me this as the visual output:

[Visual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVcU9.png)

Which is more readable that color-codes.

Notes:

1) If you want to connect them, remove the "." or change it to "-"

2) This was on Python 3.4

3) If you wanted, you could also add labels on the left and bottom of the graphs.